# Changes to be made in rejected pull request

Tags: git, github

1. Pulled the code from master branch
2. Made changes in code and submitted the pull request - PR#2 (final commit was 'commit-5')
3. Continued working from 'commit-5' and submitted another Pull request - PR#3 (Now my commit is at 'commit-9')
4. My PR#2 got rejected, now I have to make changes and resubmit it again.

The solution which comes to my mind is:

1. Pull from 'commit-5', make changes and resubmit PR again.

My Questions are:

1. Is my approach correct Or Is there is any better way to do this.
2. What happens to PR#3, if I resubmit PR#2 again. Should I revoke PR#3 and create again after PR#2 gets approved.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps for a proper flow:

1. First, take your local branch to commit that was done just before your `PR#2`

   `git reset --soft HEAD~<Number_of_commits_you_want_to_go_back>`
2. Then Undo the changes done by you in the `PR#2` and then again push to GitHub by committing these changes.

By following these steps, you will not have to worry about the other commits after `commit-5`, you have to just undo the changes done by you in the `PR#2` and then commit again with a fresh commit message.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you have two branches (`b1`, `b2`).
Using `b1` you made a PR against `master` (**PR#2**) and after that, you had cut a new branch from `b1` which is `b2` and made further changes in it(**PR#3**).

Now since you have to make some changes in **PR#2**, so simply make the changes in `b1`, push the branch and re-open the **PR#2**. 
Now take the pull of branch `b1` in `b2`. Now, `b2`(or PR#3) will also have those changes which you had to incorporate in **PR#2**.